# iOS get the place value from timeZone

Tags: ios, timezone

When I print this from my app:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]);
```

the log shows:

```
Local Time Zone (Europe/London (GMT+1) offset 3600 (Daylight))
```

or

```
Local Time Zone (US/Eastern (GMT-4) offset -14400 (Daylight))
```

Is there an interface that returns only the place? Eg **Europe/London** or **US/Eastern** respectively? I don't really want to parse the result string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
`[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] name]`

Comment: systemTimeZone or localTimeZone?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSLog(@"Time zone : %@",[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code .

```
[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleGeneric locale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
```